# sending mail in testNG without server in java

Tags: java

please how to test sending email without real server in java knowing that email is send in a project A and I want to test sending in project B

Comment: Posting some code will with your specific question will go a long way toward producing an answer. Open ended questions without specifics don't tend to do well.

Answer (score 0):

Email cannot be "sent" without an email server.

Email is modeled after a physical mail system, with a few changes.  The "sending" is the equivlent to the dropping the letter off at a post office.  It is not possible to do point-to-point email.

Email clients then open their "PO Box" or "Mailbox" on the server, and perhaps (it is optional) then downloads the mail into the local machine.

In fact, the "sending" of an email is a number of back-and-forth communication with the email server using SMTP.  Basically sending an email consists of telling the server hello, then asking about it's capabilities, and eventually asking it to validate addresses and accept a body (and optionally attachments).

So, if you really need to send a mail to a product in project B, and you cannot rely on a standalone server, you need to create a server in project B.

Comment: @GuyBouallet An excellent suggestion; however, it can only test at best the mail sending client.  To get it delivered in the other project, you could attempt to mock the server side; but, there are so many different servers with so many different options, that it's not clear your mock will be rich enough.  To mock both ends at the same time, you just implemented a mail server.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should consider mocking the mail sending. Depending on the frameworks you use, you should be able to find a good way to do it. Here is a blog illustrating a possible mechanism: http://blog.nutpan.com/2012/03/mock-testing-for-java-mail.html?m=1
You can also consider using a mocking framework like easymock or mockito to test it.